# How to activate conda environment in IIS?

Tags: python, numpy, iis, anaconda, plotly-dash

I am trying to deploy a dash app through IIS on a windows server.
The problem I am running against is that I do not know nor can I find how to activate a conda environment (in the `web.config` file?). The current configuration works fine untill I try to import numpy, which results in an error (see below).

This error does also occur when I open `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\testapp\python.exe` manually and try to import numpy through the command line. It however does **not** occur when I `exit()` out of python, activate the conda environment, run python again and then try to import numpy. Can anybody advise me on how to get this working within IIS?

### Current web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>   
            <add 
            name="Python FastCGI" 
            path="*" 
            verb="*" 
            modules="FastCgiModule" 
            scriptProcessor="C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\testapp\python.exe|C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\testapp\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" 
            resourceType="Unspecified" 
            requireAccess="Script" />

        </handlers>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
    <appSettings>
        <!-- Required settings -->
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="myapp.app.server" />
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testapp" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

### Numpy error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\testapp\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\testapp\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\testapp\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\testapp\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\testapp\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.6 from "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\testapp\python.exe",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.17.0" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: `<add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testapp" />` is that your conda environment?

Comment: No the environment is at “C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\testapp”. The PYTHONPATH you mention is the location of the Dash app (myapp.py)

Comment: @Niraj, did you manage to solve this issue?